# You must installWindows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0 including the "Debugging Tools for Windows" feature.(Chromium)

Tags: windows, google-chrome, chromium, chromium-embedded

I have almost finished building chromium from my windows desktop but I am stuck at the last step, running gn gen out/Default. I have checked my visual studio installer and Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0 has been already installed. I do not know what to do. The whole output is like the following:

```
C:\chromium\src>gn gen out/Default
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/chromium/src/build/vs_toolchain.py", line 573, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:/chromium/src/build/vs_toolchain.py", line 569, in main
    return commands[sys.argv[1]](*sys.argv[2:])
  File "C:/chromium/src/build/vs_toolchain.py", line 400, in CopyDlls
    _CopyDebugger(target_dir, target_cpu)
  File "C:/chromium/src/build/vs_toolchain.py", line 433, in _CopyDebugger
    raise Exception('%s not found in "%s"\r\nYou must install'
Exception: dbghelp.dll not found in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\dbghelp.dll"
You must installWindows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0 including the "Debugging Tools for Windows" feature.
ERROR at //build/toolchain/win/BUILD.gn:54:3: Script returned non-zero exit code.
  exec_script("../../vs_toolchain.py",
  ^----------
Current dir: C:/chromium/src/out/Default/
Command: C:/src/depot_tools/bootstrap-3_8_0_chromium_8_bin/python3/bin/python3.exe C:/chromium/src/build/vs_toolchain.py copy_dlls C:/chromium/src/out/Default Debug x64
Returned 1.
See //BUILD.gn:66:1: which caused the file to be included.
group("gn_all") {
```

Comment: You must have `Debugging Tools for Windows` installed to build Chromium.  When installing Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0, select `Debugging Tools for Windows` too

Answer (score 38, accepted):

From the [chromium docs](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/docs/windows_build_instructions.md#visual-studio):

> The SDK Debugging Tools must also be installed. If the Windows 10 SDK
> was installed via the Visual Studio installer, then they can be
> installed by going to: Control Panel → Programs → Programs and
> Features → Select the “Windows Software Development Kit” → Change →
> Change → Check “Debugging Tools For Windows” → Change. Or, you can
> download the standalone SDK installer and use it to install the
> Debugging Tools.

Comment: I like how the chromium doc is more clear than the official Microsoft doc...

Comment: Gawd, I was searching for `Debugging Tools For Windows` in the search field in the Visual Studio Installer with no luck. This answer saved the day.

Comment: Is there a way to do this via the command line?  I need to install these tools in a docker container.